# Logic Error in a Simple If Statement Practice in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, logic, conditional-statements

I am not sure why CHARGE_1 is being evaluated as .80 regardless of the quantity I input it whether it be 1 or 19. The same goes for the other if statements. I keep getting weird numbers like .80 and .64 as the output. Please help me figure out what is wrong with this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int MONTHLY_FEE = 10;
    const double CHARGE_1 = .10;
    const double CHARGE_2 = .08;
    const double CHARGE_3 = .06;
    const double CHARGE_4 = .04;
            int numChecks;
          double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;
          double charge2Total = numChecks * CHARGE_2;
          double charge3Total = numChecks * CHARGE_3;
          double charge4Total = numChecks * CHARGE_4;

    cout << "Please enter how many checks you have used.\n";
    cout << "and I will tell you how much your charge is. ";
    cin >> numChecks;

    if((numChecks > 0) && (numChecks < 20))
    {
        cout << "Your total is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) <<    
        (charge1Total + MONTHLY_FEE) << ".";
    }
    else if ((numChecks >= 20) && (numChecks <= 39))
    {
        cout << "Your total is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) <<    
       (charge2Total + MONTHLY_FEE) << ".";
    }
    else if ((numChecks >= 40) && (numChecks <= 59))
    {
        cout << "Your total is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) <<    
        (charge3Total + MONTHLY_FEE) << ".";
    }
    else if (numChecks >=60)
    {
        cout << "Your total is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << 
        (charge4Total + MONTHLY_FEE) << ".";
    }
}
```

Comment: You calculate your totals before you have checks number. Put it after **cin >> numChecks;** line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the value of numChecks before you use it.  There are four places where you use the variable uninitialized, which means the value could be anything.

In the lines

```
  double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;
  double charge2Total = numChecks * CHARGE_2;
  double charge3Total = numChecks * CHARGE_3;
  double charge4Total = numChecks * CHARGE_4;
```

numChecks could be anything, so put these lines BELOW the statement where you

```
cin >> numChecks;
```

Answer (score 0):

`chargeXTotal` vars are evaluated at compile time since you defined their formula in the variable declaration as :

`double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;`

And since `numChecks` is an uninitialized var:

`int numChecks;`

Thus `chargeXTotal` each will have already been set with a number not as you would expect it from `cin`, So the proper way is to keep the declaration of `chargeXTotal` after `cin`:

```
cin >> numChecks;
double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;
```

This will make the compiler calculates the correct value for `charge1Total` after user input not at compile time with uninitialized var.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple logic error in your code: you perform the mathematical operation with `numChecks` before you even initialize it. You accept the input of `numChecks` after you have performed the calculation with it:

```
int numChecks; // numChecks is uninitialized here; it is only defined as an int variable

// in the following 4 calculations, you multiply CHARGE_N with an uninitialized variable
double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;
double charge2Total = numChecks * CHARGE_2;
double charge3Total = numChecks * CHARGE_3;
double charge4Total = numChecks * CHARGE_4;

// here you accept the input of numChecks after you have oerformed the calculations with it
cout << "Please enter how many checks you have used.\n";
cout << "and I will tell you how much your charge is. ";
cin >> numChecks;
```

Since you do not initialize `numChecks` before you perform the mathematical operations sith it, the value used in the operation everytime you run the program is unknown, as the compiler sets the variable to some default value. Some compilers initialize the variables to zero; however, other compilers initialize it to some "*unknown*" value.

You initialize the variable `numChecks` after the compiler has performed the mathematical operation and stored the **incorrect** value in `chargeXtotal`, hence, giving you the wierd values as output.

You should change your code so that the input of `numChecks` is taken before the mathematical operation for `chargeXtotal` is done:

```
int numChecks;

cout << "Please enter how many checks you have used.\n";
cout << "and I will tell you how much your charge is. ";
cin >> numChecks;

double charge1Total = numChecks * CHARGE_1;
double charge2Total = numChecks * CHARGE_2;
double charge3Total = numChecks * CHARGE_3;
double charge4Total = numChecks * CHARGE_4;
```

Hope this helps!